# How to make this windows script skip existing files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a windows script here that takes all files in a source folder, whether they're nested or not, and moves them to one single destination folder.

However I have some duplicates within the source folders and every time it comes across one it prompts to copy or skip it. It is quite cumbersome as some of the source folders have a lot of duplicates.

Can someone advise on how to edit this script to make it auto skip any duplicates without prompting me every time or maybe even copy both and just append the name of the duplicate? Either one would work. I am still new to the whole batch script scene and it is driving me nuts.

The script I have is:

```
FOR /R "C:\source folder" %i IN (*) DO MOVE "%i" "C:\destination folder"
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're calling them duplicates, but in the context of your script, the only thing you know has been duplicated is a filename, not its content. Please confirm that you will never want to replace them regardless of their content. `For /R "C:\source folder" %I In (*) Do If Not Exist "C:\destination folder\%~nxI" Move "%I" "C:\destination folder"` Also if this really is a script, it should be, `@For /R "C:\source folder" %%I In (*) Do @If Not Exist "C:\destination folder\%%~nxI" Move "%%I" "C:\destination folder"`.

Comment: So when I say duplicate I mean in the parent source folder there may be two or more files named "a.jpg". They could exist in any number of nested folders inside of the parent folder. However their content may be different or even corrupted, which is why I am trying to un-nest them and move them to a new destination. To speed up sorting through corrupted files by hand. Currently it will move the first "a.jpg" but once it finds another one with the same name it prompts to either overwrite or skip it. I would like it to either append the next file with the same name or skip them. Did that help?

Comment: Not really, because those facts are outside of the question, which if those factors were taken into account would result in an off topic code request. Your answer is in my previous comment for the initial question as written. The first code with respect to your [[tag:cmd]] tag, and the second with respect to your [[tag:batch-file]] tag. Remaining files in the source tree, will require your additional work, to determine if they're corrupted, or have different content.

Comment: When I first read your comment the code you wrote was not there, then it appeared after a refresh. I understand what you are saying I believe, however like I said I'm still learning this so I may be using the wrong term when referring to batch scripting. I am running this directly in a cmd prompt. When I ran your second set of code with the %%I it threw an error that the %%I was unexpected. However If I run the first line of code you have, it appears to do exactly what I needed. I assumed I would need the "if not exist" I was just unsure of the syntax and positioning to add it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about that, it wasn't until I edited your question, and noticed you specified it was a script, that I added them via edit. Every command you need information on has built-in help, so use it. In this case, within your Command Prompt window, `for /?`, `if /?`, and `move /?` should have given you all you required, instead just flat out asking somebody. BTW, in the Command Prompt, you'd probably not need to see each command printed before it is ran, for that, change it to, `For /R "C:\source folder" %I In (*) Do @If Not Exist "C:\destination folder\%~nxI" Move "%I" "C:\destination folder"`.

Comment: You're right I don't know why I didn't think about that! Too many hours staring at a computer screen in frustration I guess. Thank you for the help.